# How to start/open command prompt from lock screen without signing in?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, lock-screen

Hi guys I'm wondering if it's possible to open windows command prompt from a locked windows 10 computer.
I tried using recovery mode to open cmd but it required me to sign-in first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm wondering if it's possible to open windows command prompt from a locked windows 10 computer.*

No.  You have to log into the Windows computer to do this.

You are limited to "news" type information on the Lock Screen.

To do as you are asking presents a serious security risk if other people have access to the computer.

To run commands and run apps, and to run Recovery, you need to log into the computer.

Same for Windows 10 and for Windows 11.

=========

Now if something has gone wrong and you are locked out, then try restarting in Safe Mode and try logging in that way.   Safe Mode:  Normally repeated presses of F8 on restart.

This may also allow you to recover.

==========

If you have forgotten your password and have a Microsoft Account, you can login to Microsoft Live from another computer, put in your email address and then use the Forgot Password function.

Comment: interesting, bec this video shows it being done https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVfJsXJvxlY

Comment: ...so how was it done it the video? -did you get a chance to see it?

Comment: You cannot open cmd.exe from the Windows 10 Lock Screen at least from any Windows version in the last 4 years.

Comment: so it must be from before 4 years ago?

Comment: Or from even farther back.

Comment: Oh. Well, right now I'm trying to break into my own windows 10 virtual machine, which I know the password to. In other words I want to know this for educational purposes. I do thank you for trying to help me out, though.